# prolog add two list using successor notation

Tags: list, prolog, addition

I'm new to prolog and I'm doing some exercises for practice. I am adding two list in successor notation. The question and answer should be displayed in successor notation, but for convenience, I write it in numerical.

1. List([1,1,1,1],[2,2,2,2],[3,3,3,3])
2. List([9,9,9,9],[1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,0])

I get the answer of the question two [10,10,10,10] in successor notation easily, but the answer needs us to handle the digits, which means the expect ans is [s(0),s(0),s(0),s(0),0].

Comment: Show your partial solution.

Comment: List([],[],[]).
List([H1|L1],[H2|L2],[H3|L3]) :- lsum(L1,L2,L3), sum(H1,H2,0,H3).

Comment: sum(a,b,c,d) is a equation a+b = c+d. The question ask us refer to the previous question.

Comment: Shouldn't the sum of [9, 9, 9, 9] and [1, 1, 1, 1] be [1, 1, 1, 1, 0] ?

Comment: yes, sorry. Let me edit the question. Really sorry of my mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using the simple carry over method of addition.

```
add(0, X, X).
add(s(X), Y, s(Z)) :-
    add(X, Y, Z).

% Helper to convert b/w decimal and succ notation.
sform(0, 0).
sform(N, s(S)) :-
    N > 0, N1 is N - 1,
    sform(N1, S).

sumdigits([], [], [], 0).
sumdigits([X|Xs], [Y|Ys], [Z|Zs], C) :-
    sumdigits(Xs, Ys, Zs, C1),
    (C1 = 0 -> add(X, Y, Z1); add(X, s(Y), Z1)),
    (  Z1 = s(s(s(s(s(s(s(s(s(s(Z))))))))))
    -> C = s(0)
    ;  Z1 = Z, C = 0
    ).

sumdigits(Xs, Ys, Zs) :-
    sumdigits(Xs, Ys, Zs1, C),
    (C = 0 -> Zs = Zs1; Zs = [C|Zs1]).
```

```
?- maplist(sform, [9, 9, 9, 9], X), maplist(sform, [1, 1, 1, 1], Y), sumdigits(X, Y, Z).
X = [s(s(s(s(s(s(s(s(s(0))))))))), s(s(s(s(s(s(s(s(s(0))))))))), s(s(s(s(s(s(s(s(s(0))))))))), s(s(s(s(s(s(s(s(s(0)))))))))],
Y = [s(0), s(0), s(0), s(0)],
Z = [s(0), s(0), s(0), s(0), 0]
```

Comment: I am not sure how much beginner friendly this is. Are you sure the exercise is for beginners?

Comment: another requirement is not allowed to use any built-in predicates in Prolog. I had thought for an hour base on your solution but still cannot solve it. May I have some hints, please?

Comment: this is homework from our collage, which introduces prolog and declarative programming in one lecture and one tutorial. The purpose is to let us have a taste on prolog.

Comment: My biggest problem is don't know how to convert this part to the predicate. I can get the value of C1 in my program.       Is this part a build-in predicates? Thanks
    (C1 = 0 -> add(X, Y, Z1); add(X, s(Y), Z1)),
    (  Z1 = s(s(s(s(s(s(s(s(s(s(Z))))))))))
    -> C = s(0)
    ;  Z1 = Z, C = 0
    ).

Comment: think of `(A -> B; C)` as `if A then B else C`. So that statement says that: if carry(C1) is zero then  `Z1 = X+Y`, else `Z1 = X+Y+1`.  And the next says: if the Z1 is greater than 10, set final carry(C) to 1 and Z to Z1-10 else set carry(C) to 0 and Z to Z1.

Comment: I haven't used any builtin predicates in the code itself. `maplist/3` used in the example is a library predicate.

Comment: Thanks, problem solved. I asked the question because I didn't saw these symbols in my previous question only.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231936/discussion-between-jay-and-rajashekar).